# Error in echo php include code html Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

In the code I am calling data from the database and displaying it, but there is a problem in displaying the code
I am programming a site in php html css js and I had a problem

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($fech)) {

                            echo '<section class="section-margin">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="section-title section-title--bordered">
                                    <h2>' . $row->name_cat . '</h2>
                                </div>
                              

                                
                               <div class="product-slider sb-slick-slider slider-border-single-row" data-slick-setting='{
                                    "rtl":true,
                                    "autoplay": true,
                                        "autoplaySpeed": 8000,
                                        "slidesToShow": 5,
                                        "dots":true
                                    }' data-slick-responsive='[
                                        {"breakpoint":1200, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 4} },
                                        {"breakpoint":992, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 3} },
                                        {"breakpoint":768, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 2} },
                                        {"breakpoint":480, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 1} },
                                        {"breakpoint":320, "settings": {"slidesToShow": 1} }
                                    ]'>
                                    
                                   <div class="single-slide">
                                        <div class="product-card">
                                            <div class="product-header">
                                                <a href="" class="author">
                                                dsddsdsd
                                                </a>
                                                <h3><a href="product-details.html">name</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product-card--body">
                                                <div class="card-image">
                                                    <img src="image/products/product-13.jpg" alt="">
                                                    <div class="hover-contents">
                                                        <a href="product-details.html" class="hover-image">
                                                            <img src="image/products/product-11.jpg" alt="">
                                                        </a>
                                                        <div class="hover-btns">
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quickModal"
                                                                class="single-btn">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="price-block">
                                                    <a href="#" ><span  class="price">more</span></a>
                        
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                        
                     
                         </div>
                                
                         </div>
                     </section>';}
```

Error appears
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\mk\inc\post.php on line 18

What is the solution to this problem ?
I could not find the answer

Comment: You have mixed parentheses issue, fix code with escapes, simply replace ' with \'  in whole string.

Comment: Where do I add \

Comment: ... data-slick-setting=\'{  ...   }\' data-slick-responsive=\'[ ... ]\'> ...